# Angular routing matcher doesn't call sub details page

Tags: angular, typescript

I try to use the same page for different routerLink nevigation category, on the app-routing if i use the normal path: product when i click on products link and on details work good, but if i try to use the matcher doesn't open details page,
(for test you can remove the comment on path:product and add on matcher and see how work)
can someone help me to fix this problem? thanks

[stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routing-match#comment-formatting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should understand how `matcher` works. The documentation is not very good about it, so I will try to explain. When you pass the `UrlSegment[]` to `matcher`, it will try to match the url and then it will pass the remaining part of the url to the child router.

In order to make it work properly, you should specify what part of the url was consumed by the parent router, and the remaining part will be passed to the child router. If you don't specify that, it will assume that the parent router consumed whole url, and it will pass empty string to child router.

In your example, you want to navigate to:

```
products/product-details/1
```

Because you didn't specify that your parent router only consumed `products` part of the url, it will assumed that your parent router consumed whole url `products/product-details/1`, and only the empty string will be pass to the child router.

So, to solve this, you should specify that your parent router consumed only `products` part of the url, and the remaning part will be pass to the child router.

I updated your example will working code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routing-match-vhqdrf?file=src/app/products/products-routing.module.ts

NOTE: I removed part about the `computers` and `electronics` because you should create a new `matchers` for them, since they are not in `ProductsModule`.